# Canonical projection on submanifold $M^k $ over a hyperplane $H^{n}$ is immersion

Tags: differential-topology

Let $M^k \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, $M$ compact and $2k\leq n$. Show tha exist a $n$-hyperplane $H^n\subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ such that if $\pi:H^{n}\oplus (H^n)^{\perp}\rightarrow H^{n}$ is the projection then $\pi\vert_{M}:M\rightarrow H^{n}$ is an immersion.
This is a exercise where suppose to use Sard's Theorem, let me a hint please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**: Can you use Sard's Theorem to show that there is a unit vector in $\Bbb R^{n+1}$ that belongs to *no* tangent space $T_xM$?

Comment: But, the tnagent space $T_x M$ is a linear subspace with dim$T_x M$=n emmbeded in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ then theres at least one vector there that dont belongs to $T_x M$. I still do not see.

Comment: No, consider the map $f\colon TM \to\Bbb R^{n+1}$ given by $f(p,v) = v$. What do you know about its image, since $\dim TM = 2k<n+1$?

Comment: It should not cover whole $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$

Comment: Or using Compact Whitney embedding

Comment: This is really part of the proof of Whitney Embedding. But, in fact, you don't need compactness to do this problem (or, in fact, to prove the strong version of Whitney Embedding). Sard's Theorem doesn't need compactness, just keeping track of dimensions.

Comment: Since the compactness for $M$ the proof need be a particular case. A hint that I read say the next: Use the projectivization of the tangent bundle of M and define a function on $\mathbb{R}$P$^{n-1}$

Comment: Way too complicated. Just show that if $H$ has normal vector $a$, with $a\notin T_xM$ for any $x\in M$, then $\pi|_M$ is an immersion.